# cleaner way of declaring a variable together with an if statement

Tags: c#

Could someone show me a better method to write something like this?
I mean, I know that I could just tell it to take it straight from the textbox and preset the path but I would still like to know how to write something like this cleaner.

```
            if (opt_textbox.Text == "")
                opt = $"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic)}\\TRNX_CONV\\";
            else
                opt = opt_textbox.Text;
```

Comment: I think your code is fine as-is. I can think of two ways you could rewrite your code, although whether they are "better" is arguable.

1) Taking the first non-empty value. `opt = new [] {opt_textbox.Text, $"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic)}\\TRNX_CONV\\"}.FirstOrDefault(x => ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));`

2) Ternary: `opt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(opt_textbox.Text) ? $"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic)}\\TRNX_CONV\\" : opt_textbox.Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine.

Here is another way:

```
var x = (opt_textbox.Text == "")
      ? $"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic)}\\TRNX_CONV\\"
      : opt_textbox.Text;
```

It could be better to use string.IsNullOrEmpy or IsNullOrWhitespace instead of `==""`;

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine.

If you want to be fancy, in c#>=7, you can use pattern variables.

```
string opt = opt_textbox.Text is var text && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
           ? text
           : "Empty";
```

or the 'long form' version

```
if( opt_textbox.Text is var text && text != "") 
{ 
  opt = text;
} 
else 
{
  opt = "Empty"
}
```